# Set X11 cursor to arrow

Tags: c, x11, xlib, mouse-cursor

I attempted the following in a call to XCreateWindow():

```
unsigned long ctt_attribute_mask = CWWinGravity | CWCursor;

ctt_attributes->win_gravity = NorthEastGravity;
ctt_attributes->cursor = XC_arrow;

ctt_window = XCreateWindow(dpy, parent, ctt_xpos, ctt_ypos,
             ctt_xy_size, ctt_xy_size, ctt_border,
             ctt_depth, ctt_class, ctt_visual,
             ctt_attribute_mask, ctt_attributes);
```

This creates the window, but it doesn't affect the pointer when it rolls over the window.

I want to use the user's desktop environment's standard pointer cursor when the mouse appears over my window.

Xlib is required, because this is a toolkit-agnostic program.

**ETA**: Additional context is available; see `create_ctt_window` starting on line 35 in the [source file](https://github.com/mbt/alltray/blob/v0.7.6dev/src/alltray-ctt-helper.c#L35).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `ctt_attributes->cursor = XCreateFontCursor(dpy, XC_arrow);`
2. This is not the desktop environment's standard pointer cursor, this is the X11 rather ugly bitmapped cursor. If you want themed cursors, use libXcursor. I have no experience with it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer to libXcursor.  Now I just have to figure out how to use it.  The APIs listed in the man page for it, well, they don't seem to work; `char *XcursorGetTheme (Display *dpy)` returns NULL even for theme names that are present in the cursor themes directory, and `Cursor XcursorLibraryLoadCursor (Display *dpy, const char *name)` doesn't seem to actually do anything either. Of course, I'm probably doing something wrong. Seems I'm damned when it comes to low-level X11 programming.  :)

Comment: Aha. It turns out that libXcursor cannot discover what the in-use mouse theme is on the display.  I'll have to resort to discovering that from the underlying WM and/or DE in a WM/DE dependent fashion. So much for portability...

Answer (score 2):

Here's the example from The Xlib Programming Manual, vol 1, p 182.

```
#include <X11/cursorfont.h>
int cursor_shape = XC_arrow;
Window window;
Cursor cursor;
cursor = XCreateFontCursor(display, cursor_shape);
XDefineCursor(display, window, cursor);
/* Now cursor will appear when pointer is in window */
```

So it looks like n.m. is spot-on. You need to call `XCreateFontCursor` to translate XC_arrow (which is just an integer that designates the cursor's location in the font's encoding vector) into a Cursor resource. I think the Cursor resource is just an integer, too. That's why you get no compile error. But you do indeed have a type mismatch.